# Excel VBA - concatenate string

Tags: string, excel, string-concatenation, vba

I am trying to learn VBA and had gotten some help on how to increment my row number on a workbook that I am referencing by using CStr.  On the below I am attempting to concatenate a cell on the other workbook with string 'year'.  If I take out the 'year' it works fine but with 'year' added it does not work.  There must be something I am doing wrong but I cannot figure it out.

```
Dim year As String
year = "16"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[Junk Work File.xlsx]Total'!R" & CStr(r) & "C1" & year
```

Comment: Define 'does not work' for us. What happens? An error? Unexpected results?

Comment: ..................use **"year"**

Comment: Try using a different name for the variable, it may not be working because 'year' is a reserved word.  Try strYear instead.

Comment: I think a part of the problem lies in the end result. Since `year` is defined as "16", then your resultant string is (approximately): `=JunkTotal!R1C116` . That creates a formula that looks to the cell in column 116. I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: Take out the "1" in "C1":  & "C" & year

Answer (score 0):

Try using '+' instead of '&'.

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[Junk Work File.xlsx]Total'!R" & CStr(r) & "C1" + year
```

Or

You can use Concatenate function

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Concatenate("='[Junk Work File.xlsx]Total'!R" & CStr(r) & "C1" , year)
```